# Can't resolve all parameters for Push: (?, ?)

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic2

I'm new at Ionic2.I am developing a test application on ionic 2,There are many features in it(SMS,Call Number,Chart,MySql,Push ...)I just followed the steps for push notification.[push notification link](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/).But I get an error and I do not get the cause.Where do i make mistakes

**app.component.ts**

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
   import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
   import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
   import {
   Push,
   PushToken
     } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

  import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
  @Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [Push]

})
export class MyApp {
   rootPage:any = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
      SplashScreen,public push:Push) {
       platform.ready().then(() => {
       // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
     statusBar.styleDefault();
     splashScreen.hide();
    });

   this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
    return this.push.saveToken(t);
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
    console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });

       this.push.rx.notification()
       .subscribe((msg) => {
       alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
      });

     }
   }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
 import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
 import {CallNumber} from '@ionic-native/call-number';
 import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';
 import {ChartPage} from '../pages/chart/chart';
 import {CallNumberPage} from '../pages/call-number/call-number';
 import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
 import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
 import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
 import {CloudSettings,CloudModule} from '@ionic/cloud-angular';


 import { MyApp } from './app.component';
 import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
 import {CanvasPage} from '../pages/canvas/canvas';
 import {SqlitePage} from '../pages/sqlite/sqlite';
 import {MysqlPage} from '../pages/mysql/mysql';
 import {ServiceProvider} from '../providers/datamember';
 import {ListPage} from '../pages/list/list';

  const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
   'app_id': 'xxxxxxx',
 },
    'push': {
      'sender_id': 'xxxxxxxxx',
     'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
     },
       'android': {
       'iconColor': '#343434'
       }
     }
   }
 };


   @NgModule({
    declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ChartPage,
    CallNumberPage,
    CanvasPage,
    SqlitePage,
    MysqlPage,
    ListPage
   ],
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,

    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
   ],
   bootstrap: [IonicApp],
   entryComponents: [
   MyApp,
   HomePage,
   ChartPage,
   CallNumberPage,
   CanvasPage,
   SqlitePage,
   MysqlPage,
   ListPage
 ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    CallNumber,
    SMS,
    SQLite,
    Toast,
    ServiceProvider,
    HttpModule,


       {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]
    })
  export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the cloud client setup to use `Push` . Check [here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#prerequisites)

Add `CloudModule` to imports.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings), //here
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
   ],
```

Comment: @UrvishPatel can you form a question with  a [mcve]? cant really tell what the issue could be without it

Comment: I know it but i am asking you have you another solution or something wrong with by my code

Comment: @UrvishPatel I cant tell whats wrong with your code.. My answer specifically resolves OP's question.. Since OP had not configured Ionic Cloud module..You must have missed something